# Hacked list of AD logins and passwords

Tags: passwords, windows, active-directory, system-compromise

An organization my friend works for was recently hacked, and the hackers published a file with over 100,000 names and passwords, including theirs. An IT person in the organization told me that the hackers seem to have found an encrypted file with logins and passwords in Active Directory (it's a Windows-based system) and were able to decrypt it.

I can't understand this - do modern servers actually save all logins and passwords in a single (encrypted) file?  I thought that modern systems don't even have to keep copies of passwords, and instead can only verify them through hashing-based protocols.  Is there a reasonable explanation for what happened that doesn't involve gross negligence and incompetence on the part of the system admins?

Comment: In Windows based SoHos setups (no AD) stealing the SYSTEM and SAM files from the Windows/system32 folder is enough to get the NTLM hashes, which can be cracked with rainbow tables. A very popular tool for that is called Ophcrack

Comment: Are such setups still used?

Comment: Everything up to Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10 should have that very same structure, I have no clue about Windows Server 2022/Windows 11

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to answer, considering the lack of information. Generally, I don't think in modern and fresh AD installation such easily crackable file can possibly exist, at least I've never heard of such. However, it's possible that: a) the system was created years back, and still uses unsafe hashes (quite unlikely though), or b) encryption settings were downgraded, e.g. for compatibility, or c) the leaked credentials were all having weak passwords, or d) published passwords were taken not actually from AD but from some app/db/file storage/backup with weak or absent encryption

Comment: @SirMuffington if you can provide evidence of that, that could serve as a possible answer. If the SAM contains the enterprise's hashes, that might be sufficient for the context.

Comment: @schroeder I doubt my comment is ripe enough for an answer... Some more information: the files are stored under system32/config folder, the SAM and SYSTEM files are part of the registry which do contain NTLM hashes, but both files are needed for use with Ophcrack. Even mimikatz can be used to extract these files AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

On-premise Active Directory stores NTLM hashes of passwords in the `NTDS.dit` file on the domain controllers. If you have Domain Admin rights (or a backup of the domain controller) then you can extract the password hashes using a tool like [NtdsAudit](https://github.com/Dionach/NtdsAudit), and there are various other ways that you can extract them over the network with the appropriate privileges. You can then try and crack the hashes to obtain the clear text passwords - although whether you'll be successful depends on how strong the passwords are.

It is possible to configure AD to store passwords using [reversible encryption](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/store-passwords-using-reversible-encryption), which means that they could just be dumped out by anyone with the access listed above - but it's a pretty rare configuration (I've only seen it a handful of times).

In terms of how you can work out if these passwords do come from AD, there are a couple of things you can look at:

- Does the list of usernames and passwords match the accounts in AD?
- Assuming reversible encryption isn't enabled, are any of the passwords too strong to be realistically cracked from the NTLM hashes (for example, you're never going to crack a 15 character random hash).

If either of those is not true, then it's likely that the passwords came from somewhere else (such as a compromise web application).

100,000 users is a pretty big AD domain, which suggests that it's a large organisation who's got compromised. If they haven't brought in professional forensics/IR people to try and answer these questions, then that would be pretty incompetent.